# Matplotlib Title location

Tags: python, matplotlib

i have this several plots and want to correct the title name location. I want to make the Vertical Acceleration (y) on the middle left vertically and the Flare Time (x) on the middle bot horizontally also the Test Title on middle top. Basically I want to be able to move the label location.
Below is the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter


x = ip.RESULTS
y = Vert

xy = np.vstack([x,y])
z = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)

idx = z.argsort()
x, y, z = x[idx], y[idx], z[idx]

nullfmt = NullFormatter()         # no labels

# definitions for the axes
left, width = 0.1, 0.65
bottom, height = 0.1, 0.65
bottom_h = left_h = left + width + 0.02

rect_scatter = [left, bottom, width, height]
rect_histx = [left, bottom_h, width, 0.2]
rect_histy = [left_h, bottom, 0.2, height]

# start with a rectangular Figure
plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 8))

axScatter = plt.axes(rect_scatter)
#plt.plot(np.unique(x), np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 1))(np.unique(x)))
#plt.plot(np.unique(x), np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 1))(np.unique(x)))
axHistx = plt.axes(rect_histx)
axHisty = plt.axes(rect_histy)

# no labels
axHistx.xaxis.set_major_formatter(nullfmt)
axHisty.yaxis.set_major_formatter(nullfmt)

# the scatter plot:
axScatter.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=50, edgecolor='')

# now determine nice limits by hand:
binwidth = 1
xymax = np.max([np.max(np.fabs(x)), np.max(np.fabs(y))])
lim = (int(xymax/binwidth) + 1) * binwidth

bins = np.arange(-lim, lim + binwidth, binwidth)
axHistx.hist(x)
axHisty.hist(y, orientation='horizontal')

plt.title('test title', fontsize=20)
axHisty.set_xlabel("Vertical Acceleration")
axHistx.set_xlabel("Flare Time")
```

and the results look like this. Any help would be appreciated
[image]

Comment: You want the `axScatter`'s `set_xlabel` and `set_ylabel` methods, and the `axHistx.set_title` method?

Comment: Such a poorly explained question that it is hard to understand what you eventually want

Comment: yes, i want to move the label position to be exact @bnaecker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three Axes objects (plot rectangles to say it sloppy) in your graph: `axScatter` is your main chart in the bottom left. `axHisty` is the histogram on the right and `axHistx` is the histogram on the top. Your axis titles belong on the y- and x-axis of `axScatter`. So just do:

```
axScatter.set_ylabel('Vertical Acceleration')
axScatter.set_xlabel('Flare Time')
```

Based on your vague question I have no idea where you want the `"test title"`, but just figure out which Axes object is best and give it an `xlabel`, `ylabel` or `title`.